# How to mouse hover using Blue prism on a web page

Tags: mouseover, blueprism

I am trying to mouse hover a menu option using blue prism. I tried HTML/Win32/AA/Region mode while spying but none of them worked. If I click on that element, I will be navigated to a different page.

Any pointers will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you still need an answer on that as this question is more than month old.

If I understood you correctly, you want to hover mouse pointer over menu and then select one of the options from the drop down list. If so, there might be some options to achieve that without clicking on the menu itself.

1. If you want to open same link every time you navigate through this website, then you can launch the target URL instead of navigating through the menu.
2. Some HTML elements doesn't need to be visible to be active, on some websites you can 'click' on menu item without it being presented in form of drop down list. You can try to spy that element and navigate directly to it. If you won't be able to spy it you can search for correct element in application tree (Application Modeller -> Select some element -> click on arrow next to Identify button -> Open Application Navigator). Then you can use Mouse Click on that element via Navigate stage.
3. I've tried to imitate mouse hover on some website by spying whole browser window with Win32 mode, and then using Drop option in Navigate stage, giving the menu exact coordinates. Seems to be working, you can try this option as well.
4. You can test how menu reacts on Focus method in Navigate stage, but I wouldn't get my hopes up with this option.

If you share link to the website, then maybe I'll be able to help more.